# vscode-server serve-local extension content is not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

**vscode-server serve-local** (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) is launched on remote machine with access to internet without any proxy.

I can search and install new extensions, but their description and screenshots (about page) is not shown - first problem!

And most importantly, extensions which should display some content are just showing empty screens. Like "Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code" is showing list of DB and Tables in Side Bar (proving that it works), but then opens a blank page instead of working window.

Did someone had this problem? Is it about **serve-local** being still in beta, or remote/proxy/security issue?

Any help is appreciated. This ruins otherwise perfect setup of remote development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

That happen to me over the weekend. I've been using coder-server on Amazon AWS when I'm remote. I access it through one of my domains using a Let's Encrypt SSL. I decided to install code-server at home and installed it in a docker container on one of my Raspberry Pi 4's. I created a host for the container called vscode.local. Works great but, I had the same problem you were having. Per the documentation https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/ipad, using coder-server local you're most likely accessing coder-server with http and not https. To solve your issue all you need to do is create a self-signed SSL and make sure you access your instance with HTTPS and not HTTP.

If you need help on creating a self-signed SSL, this is a good how to article to follow. https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development

I personally installed code-server using docker container and use NGINX-Proxy Manager to access the local container through a local host name. NGINX Proxy Manager which allows you easily install your self-signed SSL. That solved the problem I was having.

Here is a link to the coder-server guide on how to use self-signed SSL's. https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/guide#https-and-self-signed-certificates

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Did not expect HTTP to be causing this.
I switched to serve-local --host 127.0.0.1 and forwarded the port via SSH session, solved for now. But I will try the HTTPS approach.

Comment: I didn't either.It was quite the surprise. If you need any help, just let me know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Oracle Developer Tools for VS code showing blank connection dialogs when using remoting is fixed in version 21.6.0 and later. If you come across this make sure to upgrade the extension.